# Leadtools PDF viewer with continuous scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, leadtools-sdk

I'm using Leadtools SDK to build an C# WPF application that opens and shows PDF files.

At the mommet I only have two requirements:

- Continuous scroll (like in Adobe Reader)
- Zoom in/out

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out which is the right control for this. These are the main controls that Leadtools gives me:

- ImageViewer
- ImageList
- RasterImageViewer

Since I want to scroll all PDF pages I'm using ImageList control. This control is able to show multiple pages but it doesn't have any properties like ScaleFactor to control the zoom. 
ImageViewer and RasterImageViewer both have ScaleFactor but they lack the ability to show multiple pages, they only show one at a time.

Which control is the right one for my scenario? And how to approch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have posted a simple WPF demo that displays continuous multiple pages using the Leadtools.Controls.RasterImageViewer control.
This control is the same one used in the AnnotationsLayersDemo shipped with version 19 of LEADTOOLS and it is derived from the ImageViewer control. Both controls are implemented in the Leadtools.Controls.Wpf assembly.
The simple demo can be found here: http://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/CS/forums/44682/ShowPost.aspx#44682